Creation of two (Opposites are opposite)
What is the answer to this puzzle?

 


Ignore the thin white lines you see, theyre not part of the puzzle

Guys, I'm gonna make an edit soon and add an additional image which will make it more helpful. As it is right now i'm not fully satisfied with it because I think it's going to be very hard to solve without some necessary info.

The answer is

 CUBISM

Reason

 The cube’s faces represent the first 25 letters of the alphabet and they are to be read in a way that is presented by the coloured lines drawn on them. The Xs represent the 5 vowels. Notice how the cube’s opposing faces have the same logic but going in opposite directions. After identifying this go BROWN BLUE SILVER YELLOW GREEN RED in terms of faces and basically extract the letter the line points at on that face
 
 (The letter As in black just represents the letter. The directional arrows show how the alphabet is to be read per face).

The title according the OP

 Refers to Pablo Picasso and Georges Braque the two co-founders of CUBISM.


Well done! The "creation of two" was just a reference to those who created the term.

Thanks! I will add that in. I think the diagrams above made this puzzle too trivial imo!

That being said, your puzzles are my favorite here and I enjoy trying them out even if I have no idea on how to solve them.

Thanks. Yes I guess you're right about that, some additonal info was needed but yeah I could have chosen something that hinted towards the three paths instead.
